# Positioning window form to be bottommost

Tags: c#, winforms

I want every time you start my window form, he set at the bottom of the screen (above the taskbar)

```
  public void goBottomWindow(Form targetForm)
  {

                targetForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
                targetForm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
                targetForm.TopMost = true;
                WinApi.SetWinFullScreen(targetForm.Handle);

     }
  public class WinApi
  {
        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetSystemMetrics")]
        public static extern int GetSystemMetrics(int which);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern void
            SetWindowPos(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr hwndInsertAfter,
                         int X, int Y, int width, int height, uint flags);

        private const int SM_CXSCREEN = 0;
        private const int SM_CYSCREEN = 1;
        private static IntPtr HWND_TOP = IntPtr.Zero;
        private const int SWP_SHOWWINDOW = 64; // 0x0040

        public static int ScreenX
        {
            get { return GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN); }
        }

        public static int ScreenY
        {
            get {return 60;}
        }

        public static void SetWinFullScreen(IntPtr hwnd)
        {
            SetWindowPos(hwnd, HWND_TOP, 0, 0, ScreenX, ScreenY, SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
        }
    }
```

Using this code, it leaves my window form at the top of the screen .... but what I need is the form window positioned below.
It is possible to do this?

Sorry, my English is very bad :(

Comment: did you try `StartPostion` ?

Comment: Yes, does not work, why it also positions the window form below need her to occupy a width of 100% of the screen (it is already running).

Answer (score 1):

Why  `targetForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;` ?
isn't `FormWindowState.Normal` better for you?

Just fetch the dimension of your desktop/screen

```
var rect = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea;
targetForm.Witdh = rect.Width;
targetForm.Top = rect.Height - targetForm.Height;
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw that in your first lines it says `targetForm.TopMost = true;`
That means that your form will be **TOPMOST**, if you want your form to be *BottomMost*, you should change that to `false;`

Hope this helps! - CCB

Comment: No. Not at all. TopMost has *nothing* to do with the Y position on the screen, and *everything* to do with the Z-order